# RockPaperScissors Game (Best of 3) using TDD

Tags: java, tdd

Recently I started to study Java along with TDD.

I started to develop a RockPaperScissors game using maven and junit.... and so far so good.

It was just one round, returning a winner.... so "basically" I have 2 principal classes: RoundTest and Round like below

*class RoundTest

```
public class RoundTest {

Player player1;
Player player2;
Round round;
Player winner;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    player1 = new Player();
    player2 = new Player();
    round = new Round();
}

@Test
public void player1AndPlayer2ChooseRock_roundIsDraw() {

    //Given     

    //When
    player1.choose(new Rock());
    player2.choose(new Rock());
    winner = round.play(player1,player2);

    //Then
    Assert.assertEquals(null, winner);
}

@Test
public void player1ChooseRockPlayer2ChoosePaper_Player2Wins() {

    //Given     

    //When
    player1.choose(new Rock());
    player2.choose(new Paper());
    winner = round.play(player1,player2);

    //Then
    Assert.assertEquals(player2, winner);       
}

@Test
public void player1ChooseRockPlayer2ChooseScissors_Player1Wins() {

    //Given

    //When
    player1.choose(new Rock());
    player2.choose(new Scissors());
    winner = round.play(player1,player2);

    //Then
    Assert.assertEquals(player1, winner);
}

@Test
public void player1ChoosePaperPlayer2ChoosePaper_roundIsDraw() {

    //Given

    //When
    player1.choose(new Paper());
    player2.choose(new Paper());

    //Then
    Assert.assertEquals(null, winner);
}

@Test
public void player1ChoosePaperPlayer2ChooseScissors_Player2Wins() {

    //Given

    //When
    player1.choose(new Paper());
    player2.choose(new Scissors());
    winner = round.play(player1,player2);

    //Then
    Assert.assertEquals(player2, winner);
}

@Test
public void player1ChoosePaperPlayer2ChooseRock_Player1Wins() {

    //Given

    //When
    player1.choose(new Paper());
    player2.choose(new Rock());
    winner = round.play(player1,player2);

    //Then
    Assert.assertEquals(player1, winner);
}

@Test
public void player1ChooseScissorsPlayer2ChooseScissors_roundIsDraw() {

    //Given

    //When
    player1.choose(new Scissors());
    player2.choose(new Scissors());
    winner = round.play(player1,player2);

    //Then
    Assert.assertEquals(null, winner);
}

@Test
public void player1ChooseScissorsPlayer2ChoosePaper_Player1Wins() {

    //Given

    //When
    player1.choose(new Scissors());
    player2.choose(new Paper());
    winner = round.play(player1,player2);

    //Then
    Assert.assertEquals(player1, winner);
}

@Test
public void player1ChooseScissorsPlayer2ChooseRock_Player2Wins() {

    //Given

    //When
    player1.choose(new Scissors());
    player2.choose(new Rock());
    winner = round.play(player1,player2);

    //Then
    Assert.assertEquals(player2, winner);
}
```

*class Round

```
public class Round {

public Player play(Player player1, Player player2) {    

    Choice player1Choice = player1.getChoice();
    Choice player2Choice = player2.getChoice();

    if (player1Choice.beats(player2Choice)) {
        return player1;         
    }       
    if (player2Choice.beats(player1Choice)) {
        return player2;         
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now, I wanna add the "best of 3" functionality using TDD without break the test chain...

So I created the class MatchTest and Match.

The class Match will managed the game where the player 1 and player 2 will play up to 3 times, but I finding a hard time to design it from a TDD perspective.

The first test case will be P1 winning the first and the second round, winning the game.

*class MatchTest

```
public class MatchTest {

Match match;
Player player1;
Player player2;
Player winner;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    player1 = new Player();
    player2 = new Player();
    match = new Match();
}

@Test
public void test() {

    //Given     

    //When
    player1.choose(new Rock());
    player2.choose(new Paper());        

    //Then
    Assert.assertEquals(player1, match.getWinner(player1, player2));        
}
```

*class Match

```
public class Match {

public Object getWinner(Player player1, Player player2) {

    return player1;
}
```

I really would like some guidance or ideas...

Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards,

Thiago

Answer (score 2):

Note: check your test -- by the usual rules, Paper beats Rock.

```
public Object getWinner(Player player1, Player player2) {
    return player1;
}
```

At this point, there are two different directions you can go.

If you *don't* have a sense for where you are going next, then try to triangulate.  That means add a new test that will force you to change the implementation of getWinner.  Ideally, you choose a new test that only requires a small change.  For example, if you just switch the plays made by player1 and player2, then you should get player2 as the winner.

So you write that test, and it will fail.  Then make a small change to the implementation to make the test pass.  Then see if you can clean up the code.

If you *do* have a sense for where you are going next, then before you start worrying the next test, you might think about removing the duplication in your implementation.  In this case, the fact that a player wins is implicitly coupled to the choices that player made.  So make that fact *explicit* in your code.

So you might end up with something that looks like this:

```
private Round roundOne = new Round();

public Object getWinner(Player player1, Player player2) {
    return roundOne.play(player1, player2);
}
```

And that implementation is going to work until you start passing in players that *change their choice* from one round to the next.  So you will need to figure out what that looks like, and write some tests that implement that behavior.  Then you come back to match, and figure out what a test looks like when players start varying their strategies.

JBrains offers [The World's Best Intro to TDD](https://online-training.jbrains.ca/p/wbitdd-01) that may help.  The price is right to try it.

> Update as of August 20, 2018. The lectures down below for Series 1 and Series 2 are available as a free preview, even though the buttons might not say "Preview" right now.

He is implementing his tests and solutions in Java, but it isn't a Java tutorial -- you may occasionally need to look for other resources to clarify what he is doing in the code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The rock and paper was a typo.... we can see it by my previous tests. I am reading your answer carefully and will try do figure it out. Thank you very much for your reply